# Using VB.NET to log into Windows Live Mail?

Tags: vb.net, email

I want to make a program that tells you if you can login to an email account or not by entering their username and password into Windows Live.

It would connect to the Hotmail server and see if the user/pass combination is correct. If it can log in, it would display a label that the account is valid, if not it would say that the account is not valid.

How would I go about doing this?

Ok here's the totally incorrect code for logging in. I kind of borrowed it from sending an email:

```
Dim MyMailMessage As New MailMessage
MyMailMessage.From = New MailAddress(TextBox1.Text)
MyMailMessage.To.Add(TextBox1.Text)

Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.live.com")
SMTP.Port = 25
SMTP.EnableSsl = True
SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("textbox1.text", "textbox2.text")
SMTP.Send(MyMailMessage) // I have no idea how to get a response here... from the live server if it gives me a correct or incorrect response...
```

Can someone post an example code if they have a solution to this? Because I have no idea how to make this single handingly.

Comment: What have you tried? It just sounds like you want Stack Overflow to do this for you.

Comment: You definitely need to add more details to make  your question more specific.  Show us what you've got so far, and where exactly you're running into problems.

Comment: Well, I've tried connecting with System.net.mail. but that didn't turn out successful, since system.net.mail I usually use this for sending emails.

Comment: I haven't used Visual Basic in a while, so I'm just using my previous knowledge to see what I can make out of it...

Comment: Can you post the section of code that's not working? (Make sure you remove any passwords you might have in your code sample.)

Comment: I know that this code is totally wrong, but I only need help writing this code.

Comment: @Kevin I have yet to see any code from you. Could you edit your question to insert the code that's "totally wrong"?

Answer (score 1):

```
dim smtp as new smtpclient("smtp.live.com",25)
dim m as new mailmessage()'message must contains from, to, etc

with smtp

.usedefaultcredentials = false 'by default this is true
.credentials = new networkcredential("usuername","password")
.enablessl = true
.ishtmlbody = true
.send(m)
'or async
'.send(m,addresof enviado)' i'm not remember well if addressof is required here
end with


public sub Enviado
msgbox("mail message sended async")
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use the WebBrowser control which would allow you to access the username and password input boxes, and would allow you to click the login button. You could then see which page the user is redirected to and that would tell you in the username/password combo is correct or not.

Comment: Ok, that seems like a good idea. But, ok, what if I had textbox1 which was the (username box) and textbox2 which is the (password box). When the press login how would the text values in these to boxes go to the correct places on the webbrowser?

Comment: you would do something like this: browser.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", Info.Username); where browser is your WebBrowser control, and "username" is the ID of the input element on the page. And you would do the same thing for the password box. And then to click the login button, something like this would work:
browser.Document.GetElementsById("login").InvokeMember("click"); It will get a little trickier if the login button doesn't have an ID, but its still possible to figure out how to find it using the other methods in the Document object.

Comment: for your example, you would replace Info.Username with textbox1.Text

Comment: Ok this is really getting confusing, can anyone give me an example on visual basic 2005 or 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler or HTTP Analyzer to see what happens when you sign in with a Browser.
(I can give you a hand: A http post request is sent to https://login.live.com....)

All you have to do then is to mimic this request with the HttpWebRequest class in .NET.
It's important that you make your request as similar as the one from the Browser as possible.