# What is a good service that offers registration code and activation services for Cocoa/OSX applications?

Tags: cocoa, installation, registration, activation

I have a completed Cocoa application and would like to sell it. I have found many services that will sell your application, but not many that will also handle activation. Are there any services that will integrate activation into the installation file or are there any services that are easy to integrate (hopefully will take at max an hour to implement)? For example, SoftwareKey looks good, but it is only for Windows.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about in-application purchase of Mac-based Cocoa applications, there's [Golden % Braeburn](http://www.golden-braeburn.com/) and the new open source [Cocoa Boutique](http://github.com/fraserhess/boutique).  [Kagi](http://www.kagi.com/index.php) and [eSellerate](http://www.esellerate.net/) are also popular services for paying to activate Mac software.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a service that does both, but there are options such as the [AcquaticPrime framework](http://www.aquaticmac.com/) to take care of the licensing part. This [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889861/registration-for-cocoa-shareware) may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write your own key generator then e-junkie is a cheap and easy to use system that can process payments and issue codes. With a bit of creativity you can even use a spreadsheet to generate pre-generated codes, then it's just writing the activation code in Cocoa. Took me no more than a couple of hours.